# Display is not detected after adding a new M.2 NVMe

Tags: boot, nvidia, graphics, xorg, nvme

I have two M.2 NVMe drives (Intel 660P 2TB) on ASRock X399 Taichi. The OS is Ubuntu 20.04 on one of them. When I add a third M.2 NVMe (Seagate FireCuda 2TB), the OS loading does not complete and the black screen remains.

As I inspected `syslog`, the problem is that `gdm-x-session` is closed. `Xorg.0.log` clearly shows

```
[    12.345] (EE) No devices detected.
[    12.345] (II) Applying OutputClass "nvidia" to /dev/dri/card0
[    12.345]    loading driver: nvidia
[    12.575] (==) Matched nvidia as autoconfigured driver 0
[    12.575] (==) Matched nouveau as autoconfigured driver 1
[    12.575] (==) Matched modesetting as autoconfigured driver 2
[    12.575] (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 3
[    12.575] (==) Matched vesa as autoconfigured driver 4
[    12.575] (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
[    12.575] (II) LoadModule: "nvidia"
[    12.575] (II) Loading /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/nvidia/xorg/nvidia_drv.so
[    12.575] (II) Module nvidia: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
[    12.575]    compiled for 1.6.99.901, module version = 1.0.0
[    12.575]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    12.575] (II) UnloadModule: "nvidia"
[    12.575] (II) Unloading nvidia
[    12.575] (II) Failed to load module "nvidia" (already loaded, 0)
[    12.576] (II) LoadModule: "nouveau"
[    12.576] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/nouveau_drv.so
[    12.577] (II) Module nouveau: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    12.577]    compiled for 1.20.3, module version = 1.0.16
[    12.577]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    12.577]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 24.0
[    12.577] (II) LoadModule: "modesetting"
[    12.578] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so
[    12.578] (II) Module modesetting: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    12.578]    compiled for 1.20.9, module version = 1.20.9
[    12.578]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    12.578]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 24.1
[    12.578] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
[    12.579] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.so
[    12.579] (II) Module fbdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    12.579]    compiled for 1.20.1, module version = 0.5.0
[    12.579]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    12.579]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 24.0
[    12.579] (II) LoadModule: "vesa"
[    12.579] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/vesa_drv.so
[    12.580] (II) Module vesa: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    12.580]    compiled for 1.20.4, module version = 2.4.0
[    12.580]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    12.580]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 24.0
[    12.580] (II) NVIDIA dlloader X Driver  450.119.03  Mon Mar 29 17:58:11 UTC 2021
[    12.580] (II) NVIDIA Unified Driver for all Supported NVIDIA GPUs
[    12.580] (II) NOUVEAU driver Date:   Mon Jan 28 23:25:58 2019 -0500
[    12.580] (II) NOUVEAU driver for NVIDIA chipset families :
[    12.580]    RIVA TNT            (NV04)
[    12.580]    RIVA TNT2           (NV05)
[    12.580]    GeForce 256         (NV10)
[    12.580]    GeForce 2           (NV11, NV15)
[    12.580]    GeForce 4MX         (NV17, NV18)
[    12.580]    GeForce 3           (NV20)
[    12.580]    GeForce 4Ti         (NV25, NV28)
[    12.580]    GeForce FX          (NV3x)
[    12.580]    GeForce 6           (NV4x)
[    12.580]    GeForce 7           (G7x)
[    12.581]    GeForce 8           (G8x)
[    12.581]    GeForce 9           (G9x)
[    12.581]    GeForce GTX 2xx/3xx (GT2xx)
[    12.581]    GeForce GTX 4xx/5xx (GFxxx)
[    12.581]    GeForce GTX 6xx/7xx (GKxxx)
[    12.581]    GeForce GTX 9xx     (GMxxx)
[    12.581]    GeForce GTX 10xx    (GPxxx)
[    12.581] (II) modesetting: Driver for Modesetting Kernel Drivers: kms
[    12.581] (II) FBDEV: driver for framebuffer: fbdev
[    12.581] (II) VESA: driver for VESA chipsets: vesa
[    12.581] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for modesetting
[    12.581] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for fbdev
[    12.581] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for modesetting
[    12.581] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for fbdev
[    12.581] (EE) No devices detected.
[    12.581] (EE) 
Fatal server error:
[    12.581] (EE) no screens found(EE) 
[    12.581] (EE) 
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
     at http://wiki.x.org
 for help. 
[    12.581] (EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
[    12.581] (EE) 
[    12.586] (EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
```

As you can see, `xorg` does not detect the graphic output device.

If I remove the third M.2 drive, everything is fine.

If I boot from a Live USB, everything is fine and all three M.2 drives are recognised.

Note that the display is connected, but `xorg` does not detect it. I can see the flashing underscore when the boot gets stuck.

Why does the presence of the third M.2 drive cause `xorg` not to recognise the graphic device?

Comment: Have you updated to latest UEFI? And latest firmware for all 3 NVMe drives? Are you using U.2 connector as it says that disables one NVMe M.2. Did not know what U.2 was till read manual. Still not sure how you use it. Have you installed correct nVidia driver from Ubuntu repository? Many new systems require the very newest distribution to have latest kernel, drivers & support software. Have you tried live installer version of 21.04?

Comment: @ no, I haven't used U.2 connector. Everything is up-to-date by the official repository. The Nvidia is 450, which I believe is the latest. I haven't considered upgrading to 21.04 as I heavily use my computer and cannot afford any unexpected problem. If the problem is any of those you mentioned, I still wonder why the display device is not detected instead of the NVMe drive!

Comment: Firmware updates are not in repository. Although now some vendors support fwupdate to update hardware from Linux. https://fwupd.org/lvfs/devicelist  For my new Samsung NVMe,  I had to download a bootable ISO to update it. Only seen a few post with two NVMe drives. Have not seen issue, but does sound like it may be a hardware limit on the PCI Express (PCIe) bus channels used internally in motherboard.

Comment: @oldfred I had searched for firmware, but Seagate does not have firmware for its NVMe drives. If the problem is the firmware, it should be available in 21.04 as I can boot from the Live USB (I will try 20.04 Live USB too). I think the problem is when the OS is loaded from another NVMe drive (probably a conflict in the bus channels). Anyhow, it's strange.

Answer (score 0):

I post my solution, as it may help others. If you have a descriptive answer, please add.

The problem was a conflict in the bus channel between the NVMe drive(s) and the PCIe 1.

***The solution was to put the GPU in PCIe slot #3 instead of PCIe slot #1 (as instructed by the motherboard manual).***

I do not know

1. If it is the right solution.
2. If it is a common/expected behaviour.
3. If the problem is related to using 3 NVMe drives or Seagate FireCuda.